# C++ WinAPI Рендер HTML

Tags: html, c++, winapi

Есть ли что-небудь чтобы рендерить html на чистом C++ с WinAPI?

Comment: А COM объекты это ещё чистый с++ с WinAPI?

Comment: @KoVadim мне б библиотеку)

Comment: тогда придется извлекать с хрома или фаерфокса движок.

Comment: Что-то вроде Sciter?